# Access DOM of linked pages in Chrome bookmarks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension where I programmatically access the DOM of the bookmarked links, check for the page title and display it in the `popup.html`.

Can we programmatically access DOM of multiple URLs without having to open them?

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** Nope, not always!

**Slightly longer:** To build a page's DOM, you need to request that page's source, and build the DOM from it. Since page source might contain executable scripts that modify the DOM, this is a non-trivial operation.

**Even longer:**

You could potentially load the page's source via XHR (setting aside all authorization-related questions). It may contain a title that's usable for you in the `<head>`, but some pages modify that title dynamically, and what you grab will not be the "final" title. Even then, parsing the (static) HTML for the title can be non-trivial.

In general, you could try to load the site in an `<iframe>` and read the "final" title from there. Except a lot of sites refuse to load in an iframe, so this approach also fails.